# Can't open hadoop localhost:9000

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop is running on `localhost:50070`. The output of `jps` shows:

```
28236 TaskTracker
5223  Jps
28061 JobTracker
27955 SecondaryNameNode
27803 DataNode
27648 NameNode
```

But pig script is not getting input from `localhost:50070`.

It requires `localhost:9000` and shows:

```
can not found
localhost:9000
```

It also gives error for data storage:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=webuser, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="system":hduser:supergroup:rwx------
```

Comment: Please see the core-site.xml file.And see the value for fs.default.name

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission in the `hdfs-site.xml` as `false` to get rid of the below error

> Permission denied: user=webuser, access=READ_EXECUTE,
>   inode="system":hduser:supergroup:rwx------ –

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
        If "true", enable permission checking in HDFS.
        If "false", permission checking is turned off,
        but all other behavior is unchanged.
        Switching from one parameter value to the other does not change the mode,
        owner or group of files or directories.
    </description>
  </property>
```